# What is the shortcut for creating both braces?

Tags: xcode

In the Stanford course the lecturer uses some shortcut to create both braces when implementing a new method.  I know in Visual Studio you use TAB TAB, what do you use in Xcode?

Comment: What do you mean? (And isn't typing `{}` equally fast?)

Comment: I'm not sure how he does it but he seems to generate the braces somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xcode Preferences: Inserting closing "}" http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/3743/insertingclosingbrace.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/3743/insertingclosingbrace.png)